# I am getting array(0) in PHP yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am getting array(0) as var_dump.

```
tbl_supplierOrderDetails['user_id']array(2) {
  ["tbl_supplierOrderDetails"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tbl_userContactDetails"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Here is my API example using php yii2

```
 public function actionSuggestions()
    {   
        $listingId = Yii::$app->request->get('listing_id');
        $apiUrl = "http://example.com:8800/api/Home/view_supplierOrderDetails?listing_id=".$listingId;
        $suggestions = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
        $suggestions = json_decode($suggestions, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo "tbl_supplierOrderDetails['user_id']";
        //print_r($suggestions);
        var_dump($suggestions);
         exit;
        return $this->render('suggestions' , array(
            'listingId' => $listingId,
            'suggestions' => $suggestions,
        ));
    }
```

here is my api demo in json format.

```
 {
      "tbl_supplierOrderDetails": [
        {
          "num": 1,
          "user_id": 3496,
          "priority": "A.closed",
          "no_of_times": 5,
          "username": "eyuw",
          "company_name": "djff",
          "email": "abc@gmail.com",
          "contact_no": "9999999999",
          "origin": "abc",
          "dest": "xyz",
          "vehicle_class": "abc,
          "vehicle_type": "abc",
          "notes": "TCS_"
        }]
    "tbl_userContactDetails": [
        {
          "user_id": 500,
          "contact_name": "Mr abc",
          "contact_email": "abc@gmail.com",
          "contact_mobile": 9999999999,
          "contact_mobile2": null
        }]
    }
```

I want to display both this details in my html in different section . how can i do so by calling this api.

Comment: You need to better describe what you want to acomplish, your question doesn't tell me what you want to do well enough.

Comment: @marche thank you responding my question. i have rewrite my doubts. can you please looks it once. thank you

Comment: @marche can you please help me to get the json object and its values to fetch in html.

Comment: @GoPrestige: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as you are using unfiltered GET-param as SQL condition param.

Comment: Comment line with "json_decode" and see if anything will be in $suggestions. There's chance there will be notning initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, make sure that variable $suggestions contains what data you are expecting.

Your structure is completely wrong so, I would like to suggest you a good structure.

```
public function actionSuggestions() {
    try {
        $message = array();
        $listingId = Yii::$app->request->get('listing_id');
        if (!empty($listingId)) {
            $apiUrl = "http://example.com:8800/api/Home/view_supplierOrderDetails?listing_id=" . $listingId;
            $suggestions = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
            $suggestions = json_decode($suggestions, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

            //if $suggestions contains required data then you can return those data
            $message = ['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Data fetched succesfully', 'data' => $suggestions];

            //else build an array like what format you want
        } else {
            $message = ['status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Missing parameters.'];
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $message = ['status' => 'failed', 'message' => "Some exception occured."];
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Here you can expect json output like the following:

```
{
"status" : "success",
"message" : "Data fetched succesfully",
"data" : {

    }
 }
```